# How to better visualize Rails Models and Applications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, visualization, diagram

Is there a [RailRoad](http://railroad.rubyforge.org/) replacement or something that provides diagrams like unto it for Rails 3.x?  Presently you have to edit line 54 of app_diagram.rb from:

> ```
> (OLD) STDOUT.reopen(PLATFORM =~ /mswin/ ? "NUL" : "/dev/null")
>       to
> (NEW) STDOUT.reopen(RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /mswin/ ? "NUL" : "/dev/null")
> ```

Finally I found on their Forums that if you run it with something like [this](https://rubyforge.org/forum/forum.php?thread_id=47189&forum_id=13360):

```
  RUBYLIB=. railroad -o models.dot -M
```

It will actually run, but I didn't really get any output as per what should have appeared in the .dot file after opening it in OmniGraffle.  Further, it seems to just simply gag on more complex enhancements like Hobo.

Is anyone familiar with something new or a fork of this project that's still in development?

PS - I found two other projects, however they seem to be in less maintained states than even RailRoad:

- [Rails Application Visualizer](http://rav.rubyforge.org/)
- [Visualize Models](http://visualizemodels.rubyforge.org/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It appears that [Rails ERD](https://github.com/voormedia/rails-erd) may be what I'm really looking for at the moment.  Seems to fit the bill precisely for my original question.

Works with Rails 3 and Hobo, which was more of my intention for "sanity checking" my models against initial designs I put together when conceptualizing projects.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[RailRoady](https://rubygems.org/gems/railroady) is the updated RailRoad, for Rails 3.

BUT note that the latest version (v1.0.2) has a known [known issue](https://github.com/preston/railroady/issues/7) that breaks `rails generate scaffold`. I tend to only enable it in my Gemfile when I need to generate the diagram(s), and then I disable it.

Comment: That looks great.  Looking to use it with Hobo.  However, I did discover Rails ERD that I think may be the better solution at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You could also checkout [Schemapper](http://github.com/NathanielWroblewski/schemapper) for Rails 3.0+